# How to install Microsoft True Type fonts for Centos 7?

Tags: fonts

There is no fonts directory in `/usr/share` at all on my system. How can I go about installing Microsoft True Type fonts in Centos 7? I only need Arial and Georgia.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try install one of these using `rpm` (I'm not sure which is better):

- http://www.my-guides.net/en/images/stories/fedora12/msttcore-fonts-2.0-3.noarch.rpm
- http://nchc.dl.sourceforge.net/project/mscorefonts2/rpms/msttcore-fonts-installer-2.6-1.noarch.rpm
- http://li.nux.ro/download/nux/dextop/el7/x86_64/webcore-fonts-3.0-1.noarch.rpm

BTW, if your problem is not compatible issue, please use free/libre fonts. There are many beautiful ones, such as DejaVu, Droid and URW.

Answer (score 28):

This is documented at: http://mscorefonts2.sourceforge.net/

```
yum install curl cabextract xorg-x11-font-utils fontconfig
yum install https://downloads.sourceforge.net/project/mscorefonts2/rpms/msttcore-fonts-installer-2.6-1.noarch.rpm
```

Comment: worked for me...

Answer (score 1):

You may want to install group of packages `fonts` from `epel-release`:

```bsh
yum install -y epel-release
yum update -y
```

```bsh
yum groupinstall -y "fonts"
```

Comment: nice even Japanese fonts are not display previously install wine but then got lot of updates updates updates and thats just fix my issues

Answer (score 0):

A lot of additional packages related to fonts and media is available in this repository mentioned in the CentOS Wiki.

```
yum install wine
```

Installs most all the fonts needed, when the repository is added, as per the wiki here: https://wiki.centos.org/TipsAndTricks/MultimediaOnCentOS7

```
yum -y install http://li.nux.ro/download/nux/dextop/el7/x86_64/nux-dextop-release-0-5.el7.nux.noarch.rpm
```

I'm not sure how trustworthy the sources in that repository is, but the same can be said for most anything regardless of source - until we have a more widespread and healthy Linux auditing community.